# Flutter Android - How to disable the Android back Button for the whole App?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to block the Back button in the Android Bottom Bar for the whole Application. User should never be able to go back with this Button inside the App.

I already know `WillPopScope()` to block this on certain Screens. It doesnt work if I wrap WillPopScope around the MaterialApp.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: have you tried this into the WillPopScope()
`onWillPop: () async => false`

Comment: @theredboy like I said I already tried it out but it only works for the pages I used it on. I need an option to deactivate the Back Button for the whole App without calling WillPopScope all the time